# how to group validations in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, validation

I have a webpage which contains a registration form and a login form where the user can either register or login.

My problem is when I tried to register the validations on login textboxes stop request from going to the server. Also, when I login from that page, then the validation controls on registration form control stop request from going to server. What should I try?

I have tried to use an update panel, but that doesn't work.

Here is my code:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <table width="400px" style="height:30px">
            <tr>
                <td class="style3" colspan="2">
                    <div class="register-bg">
                        <div class="padl20 padt5">
                            <span style="color:#2D432C">Registration Here</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table id="hpreg" style="height:380px; width: 358px;">
            <tr >
                <td style="width: 159px">
                    <b>Full Name</b>
                </td>
                <td style="width: 187px" class="wdth180">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txt_nam" runat="server" Width="170px" CssClass="textfield"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" 
                    ControlToValidate="txt_nam" ErrorMessage="Please enter Name" ForeColor="Red">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 159px">
                    <b> Father Name</b>
                </td>
                <td class="wdth180" style="width: 187px">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txt_fnam" runat="server" Width="170px" 
                    CssClass="textfield"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" 
                    ControlToValidate="txt_fnam" ErrorMessage="Please enter father name" 
                    ForeColor="Red">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 159px">
                    <b> Gender</b>
                </td>
                <td class="wdth180" style="width: 187px">
                    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server" RepeatColumns="2" 
                    ToolTip="Enter Your Gender" Width="160px" CssClass="radio wdth130">
                    <asp:ListItem Value="M">Male</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="F">Female</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:RadioButtonList>
                </td>
            </tr>
```

.....

and login html on same page is this:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" runat="server" 
contentplaceholderid="ContentPlaceHolder2">
    <table width="240px" >
        <tr style="height:28px;">
            <td>
                <b><asp:TextBox runat="server"  ID="TextBox1" CssClass="textfield"/></b>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TextBox2" TextMode="Password" CssClass="textfield"  />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="height:28px;">
            <td><asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server">Forget Password</asp:LinkButton>
            </td>
            <td> <asp:Button ID="btn_login" CssClass="medimum-btn wdth45" runat="server" Text="Login" onclick="btn_login_Click" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="height:28px;">
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <div class="fleft">
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="fleft padl5">
    </div>
    <div class="fleft padl5">
        <br />  
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Use the `ValidationGroup` attribute of your validators and summary...split them between the two areas, and make sure the buttons that initiate the postback are aligned to the correct group

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the `ValidationGroup` attribute on your validators and summary.

Create two groups, one for your login and one for you register.

Here is some untested code to give you an idea...

```
<asp:Panel runat="server" id="pnlLogon" DefaultButton="btnLogon">
  <asp:ValidationSummary runat="server" id="sumLogon"
    ValidationGroup="valLogonGroup" />
  Username: <asp:TextBox runat="server" id="txtUsername" />
  <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtUsername"
    ValidationGroup="valLogonGroup" ErrorMessage="Provide Username"/><br/>
  Password: <asp:TextBox runat="server" id="txtPassword" />
  <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtPassword"
    ValidationGroup="valLogonGroup" ErrorMessage="Provide Password"/><br/>
  <asp:Button runat="server" id="btnLogon" ValidationGroup="valLogonGroup"
    Text="Logon"/>
</asp:Panel>
<asp:Panel runat="server" id="pnlRegister" DefaultButton="btnRegister">
  <asp:ValidationSummary runat="server" id="sumRegister"
    ValidationGroup="valRegisterGroup" />
  Full Name: <asp:TextBox runat="server" id="txtName" />
  <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtName"
    ValidationGroup="valRegisterGroup" ErrorMessage="Provide Full Name"/><br/>
  Password: <asp:TextBox runat="server" id="txtPassword" />
  <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtPassword"
    ValidationGroup="valRegisterGroup" ErrorMessage="Provide Password"/><br/>
  <asp:Button runat="server" id="btnRegister" ValidationGroup="valRgisterGroup"
    Text="Register"/>
</asp:Panel>
```

I've put them into `<asp:Panel>` to take advantage of the `DefaultButton`.  That means that if you press the `enter` or `return` key when in a textbox in the `<asp:Panel>`, the correct `<asp:Button>` is clicked... and as the individual buttons are linked to a particular `ValidationGroup` only the validators for that group will be fired.

Answer (score 1):

Validation Group should be used in this case:

```
 <table width="240px">
     <tr style="height: 28px;">
         <td>
             <b><asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TextBox1" CssClass="textfield"  
                             ValidationGroup="loginGrp"/></b>
         </td>
         <td>
             <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TextBox2" TextMode="Password" 
                          CssClass="textfield"  ValidationGroup="loginGrp" />
         </td>
     </tr>
    <tr style="height: 28px;">
         <td>
             <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" CauseValidation="false" 
                             runat="server">Forget Password</asp:LinkButton>
         </td>
         <td>
             <asp:Button ID="btn_login" CssClass="medimum-btn wdth45" runat="server" 
                         Text="Login" ValidationGroup="loginGrp"
                         OnClick="btn_login_Click" />
         </td>
     </tr>
```